# Programs not working as planned

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

In my code I successfully printed the name on the screen but now I need to print only my last name. While it still prompts the whole name only the last name will appear on the screen. I have kept trying but I am unable to figure it out.

My code:

```
include irvine32.inc

title Read5

.data

outmsg DB " Will Smith: ",0    ;promts here will smith but on screen only smith

len    DW 0

.code

main proc

mov ecx, 5

mov edx, offset outmsg

call writestring

call crlf

sub eax,eax

ShowChar:

sub eax,eax

mov al, [ebx]

call writechar

sub ebx, 1

loop showChar

Exit 

main endp

end main
```

Comment: please, correctly format your code.

Comment: I'm not familiar with irvine32.inc, but 1) it appears you are not initializing the read pointer (ebx), and 2) you are then decrementing it where it seems you should be incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to setup the pointer in EBX.

```
 mov  ebx, offset outmsg + 6  ; +6 to skip " Will "
 mov  ecx, 5
ShowChar:
 sub  eax, eax
 mov  al, [ebx]
 call writechar
 add  ebx, 1                  ; don't subtract here
 loop ShowChar
```

Of course you could also print the last name the same way you did for the complete name.

```
 mov  edx, offset outmsg + 6  ; +6 to skip " Will "
 call writestring
 call crlf
```